# Acceder a base de datos remota con Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

Mi consulta es esa. Tengo delphi 10. Con algun componente como FireDac puedo acceder a alguna base de datos sql ubicado en un servidor de host?

La idea es utilizar una web para mostrar los datos , pero utilizar una aplicacion delphi de escritorio como administrador de la misma. Para cargar clientes / facturas desde la aplicacion desktop.

Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Si tu DB está expuesta en ese Servidor de Host, no veo problema. Pero si no lo está, entonces no podrás.

Comment: Deberia de fijarme bien. Porq estoy aprendiendo y hace tiempo probe con Hostinger( que tiene incorporado MariaDb) pero desconzco sinceramente.

Comment: Si la DB es accesible para conexión remota, por supuesto que se puede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te encuentras con algún servidor que te permite acceso directro, si podrás conectar a la Base de Datos utilizando FireDAC sin problemas., pero no suele ser lo habitual.

La mayoría de servidores de Internet, sobre todo los hosting públicos, no permiten acceso directo a las Bases de Datos, por temas de seguridad, de forma que el acceso a los SGBD's sólo se permite desde el propio servidor. Ese mismo problema lo planteé en su día [en esta entrada del blog, junto con las posibles soluciones](https://neftali.clubdelphi.com/15-aplicacion-de-acceso-a-datos-introduccion/).

Si tu servidor está entre los segundos, puedes optar por crear un WebService que te permita acceder a la Base de Datos y utilizarlo de "pieza intermedia" entre tu aplicación desktop y los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahhhhh esto yo queria llegar!! Entiendo, la DB, entonces no es accesible directamente. Deberia crear una app dentro del servidor que tenga (la autorizacion digamos de aplicar cambios), vere como me apaño, ya que esto es introduccion y todo nuevo para mi. Ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Correcto, a eso me refería. Puedes encontrar excepciones, pero en la mayoría de los casos funciona de esa manera por temas de seguridad. De todas formas puedes contactar o preguntar con los propietarios del hosting para verificarlo.